# cx_Freeze copies path

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I am using cx_Freeze to generate a windows binary for my PyQt app. But the binary installer that is generated seems to still contain references to files on MY machine. (The one that generated the binary). So I can't distribute the generated installer to other machines. When the program is launched on another machine it seems look for paths that only exist on my machine.

my setup.py looks like this:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

    """ To build on windows: python.exe setup.py bdist_msi """

    base = None
    if sys.platform == "win32":
        base = "Win32GUI"

    setup( name = "Checkout",
           version = "0.1",
           description = "",
           options = {"build_exe" : {"includes": "atexit"}},
           executables = [Executable("checkout.py", base=base)])
```

Comment: There's nothing obvious in that code that should reference files by path, and other people (including me) have successfully built PyQt apps. How are the files in question referred to in your code?

Comment: I just use normal python paths. I noticed the paths because when an error occurs on the other person's machine it references file paths that are on my my machine.

Comment: What is a normal python path? As in `open('foo')`? There are some suggestions here: http://cx_freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html#using-data-files

Comment: I can confirm that cx_Freeze remembers local paths but doesn't use them in the typical sense. When cx_Freeze throws an error from a built executable, the error contained a path on my local machine to the throwing module, even though it was on a different machine. I suspect it uses symbolic links and hence behaves this way, and it's a potential security issue.